# Is there a way to select several ranges with e.g. Application.InputBox in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, the InputBox(Type:=8) can select one range only. Is there a way to select several ranges, like 2 or three ?

```
Dim t as Range
Set t = Application.InputBox("Select destination range:", Type:=8)
```

Something like:

```
Dim t As Ranges
Set t = Application.SomeOtherInputBox()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start to wish that the `InputBox` (or `MsgBox`) supported feature X, it's usually the time to create your own dialog instead. Just create your own user form with all the features you need and then show that instead.

In case you haven't done this before, here's an article with some sample code: [Custom VBA Message Box](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Custom_MsgBox.htm)